# Will Samaritans Become Jews When Moshiach Comes

Tags: messiah, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, resurrection-of-the-dead, non-rabbinic-judaism

I know in the Talmud there was a dispute whether or not Samaritans were actually Jews, so when moshiach comes will Samaritans become Jewish or will they just become a Bnei Noachide, also will Samaritans be resurrected from the dead when moshiach comes if when moshiach comes they are considered actually Jewish

Rebbi said: “A Cuthean is like a gentile.” Rabbi Shimon Ben Gamliel said: “A Cuthean is considered a Jew.” ([Tosefta Terumot 4:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Terumot.4.10?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), 4:12)

Comment: Where in the Talmud is this?

Comment: @DoubleAA [Shomronim](http://etzion.org.il/en/shiur-21-chapter-17-part-ii-shomronim) points to the history and references going into details about tham and pointing to [Rabbeinu Tam in Sanhedrin 63b, Tosafot s.v. assur](http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.34a?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) as well as [Tosefta Terumot 4:10, 4:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Terumot.4.10?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) and [Bava Kama 34a](http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.34a?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)

Comment: I am not aware of any souces saying that thy will become Jewish (assuming that they are not Jewish).

Comment: Why would anything change when Mashiach comes? Judaism is inherited matrilineally or achieved through conversion. Mashiach has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The dispute you mentioned regarding the Cutheans is an entirely different matter - there was a question as to whether their conversions were legitimate, and the Rabbis' you quote were on opposite sides of the debate. IIRC, it was later discovered that the Cutheans were secretely worshipping idols, cementing their status as invalid converts/non-Jews.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple.
According to Rebbi they're not Jewish, so therefore when Moshiach comes they'll be non Jews. According to Rashba"g they're Jews, so therefore when Moshiach comes they'll still be Jews. Moshiach has nothing got up do with whose Jewish or not.